# What is "IList<Classname> MethodName(Class a);" used for?

Tags: c#, .net

What is the use of IList and how does it work in the interface? Also how does it connect to the business object class.

Comment: To be precise it is: `IList<ClassType> MethodName(ClassType a)`

Comment: you should take a look at the basics of working with interfaces. take a look at this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/interfaces/ It's a little complicated and it's hard to explain in just a few lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is “IList<Classname> MethodName(Class a);” used for?

This is a method declaration where:

- `Class` is the class type of the `a` parameter.
- `MethodName` is the method name used to call it in some other code to do something using the `a` value.
- `IList<Classname>` is the returned type of the data variable returned by the method, that is here a function, after processing the `a` data.

`IList<Classname>` is a generic `IList` type where Classname is the generic parameter.

[Generics in C#](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/csharp/csharp-generics)

[Generics (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/)

[C# Tutorial Level 1](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/index.htm)

[C# Tutorial Level 2](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/csharp/csharp-tutorials)

[C# Tutorial Level 3](https://www.guru99.com/c-sharp-tutorial.html)

[Beginning Visual C# 2008 Programming (Book)](http://www.wrox.com/WileyCDA/WroxTitle/Beginning-Microsoft-Visual-C-2008.productCd-047019135X.html)

Answer (score 1):

in this case, the interface guarantees, that any class that implements it, will have a public method called `MethodName`, that accepts an object of type `ClassType` and returns an object that implements the `IList` interface- e.g. `List<ClassType>()`